# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'Unknown option 'naxtparagraph''

Tags: pdflib

I have moved a website to a new server but pdflib has stopped working and it is giving us:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'Unknown option 'naxtparagraph'' in /www/pdfGeneration.php:222 Stack trace: #0 /www/pdfGeneration.php(222): pdf_create_textflow(Resource id #39, '

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its ok. Upon further investigation I found that there was a typo in tag name. It started work when I change it to .

Can't believe that it was working with this bad tag for past 4 years.

Thanks.